# Understanding Vision Transformer Implementation in Keras: Issues with Patch Shape and Embedding Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model, vision-transformer

I'm trying to understand this implementation of vision transformers in keras.

Here is the full [code](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_with_vision_transformer/).

I can't understand why         `patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])` is returning a tensor `(batch_size,num_patches,patch_dim)` with shape of `(none,none,108)` instead of a tensor of shape `(none,144,108)`, in this case is returned only one patch and I can

The dimension of `patches` before being reshaped is `(none,12,12,108)` in which 12 and 12 are the height and width of all the patches in the image

```
class Patches(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
        return patches
```

Later this `tensor` is then passed to the `PatchEncoder()` that passes this `108 elements patch` in a `64 dimension dense layer` but this should not be done for each of the 144 `patches` instead of just one(the returned `patch` of `Patches()`)?

So that I can have an `embedding layer` for each of the `144 patches` I have `64 dimension vector elements` all different from each other based on the corresponding patch?

```
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )

    def call(self, patch):
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
        return encoded
```

So I thought that the `embedding layer` should be something like this in which for each `patch` I have different values based on the values in the actual patch

```
**Embedding layer that I think should be returned**
    0.[0 0 0 ... 0]
    1.[1 1 1 ... 1]
    .
    .
    .
    143.[143 143 143 ... 143]
```

Instead of this in which all the values in the initial `patches` are the same because of the `shape` return in `tf.reshape()`

```
**Embedding layer that I think is returned but I don't understand if it makes sense**
    0.[0 0 0 ... 0]
    1.[0 0 0 ... 0]
    .
    .
    .
    143.[0 0 0 ... 0]
```

My question is how passing a `tensor` of shape `(none,none,108)` make sense with this `ViT` implementation?

Here is also the summary of the model:

```
 input_3 (InputLayer)           [(None, 224, 224, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 data_augmentation (Sequential)  (None, 72, 72, 3)   7           ['input_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 patches_2 (Patches)            (None, None, 108)    0           ['data_augmentation[1][0]']      
                                                                                                  
 patch_encoder_2 (PatchEncoder)  (None, 144, 64)     16192       ['patches_2[0][0]']
```

Answer (score 0):

In the implementation of the `Vision Transformer model`, each patch is first passed through a `PatchEncoder` layer, which consists of a projection layer and an `embedding layer`. The projection layer maps the 108-dimensional patch representation to a `64-dimensional vector`, while the `embedding layer` adds a positional encoding to each patch. The positional encoding is a vector that is added to the patch representation to encode its position in the image.

However, it is important to note that the same `64-dimensional vector` is used for each `patch`, while the positional encoding is different for each `patch`. This is because the projection layer is shared across all the patches, so **it produces the same 64-dimensional vector for each patch**. The positional encoding, on the other hand, is **unique** to each patch, as it depends on the position of the patch in the image.